# The code I wrote with hand tracking module and mediapipe gives an error

Tags: python, mediapipe, cvzone

I was making the sound off/on video when I closed my hand, but I got an error in the first code, what is the reason?

I get the following error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\yegen\Desktop\ses denemeeeeee\sesdeneme2.py", line 15, in <module>    
    detector = htm.handDetector(detectionCon=0.5)
  File "c:\Users\yegen\Desktop\ses denemeeeeee\elizlememodulu.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
  File "C:\Users\yegen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 114, in __init__  
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\yegen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 258, in __init__    
    self._input_side_packets = {
  File "C:\Users\yegen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 259, in <dictcomp>  
    name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
  File "C:\Users\yegen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 513, in _make_packet    return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

And this is my code:

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np 
import handtrackingmodule as htm
import math


###############################
wCam, hCam = 640, 480
###############################
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)

detector = htm.handDetector(detectionCon=0.5)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    
    cv2.imshow("İmg", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np 
import handtrackingmodule as htm
import math


###############################
wCam, hCam = 640, 480
###############################
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)

detector = htm.handDetector(detectionCon=0.5)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    
    cv2.imshow("İmg", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```